# How to create a similar Ruby method using symbol?

Tags: ruby, symbols

I have been reading a Ruby book where I encountered below code to describe symbols

```
def walk(direction)
  if direction == :north
    # ...
  end
end
```

I tried and failed to create a similar method ( where a comparison is made against a symbol such as

`direction == :north`

because most of the time I have seen symbols being used something like `param[:name]`, so in my code I tried `:north = 1 or :favourite = 'ruby'` but got syntax error.

Is it really possible to have such a comparison using a symbol alone (without hash) ie instead of

```
if "ruby" == param[:name]
end

if "ruby" == :name
end
```

I am not sure if I have expressed the question clearly, if not I shall try and reword it.

Comment: Yes, the question is a bit unclear

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Symbols are rather like identifiers, or a special version of strings.

With strings, you can have

```
str1 = 'SYM'
```

and

```
str2 = 'symbol'
str2 = str2[0,3].upcase
```

and now there are *two* identical strings in different places in memory. Ruby has to compare all the characters to evaluate `str1 == str2`.

However symbols are unique - you can't do character manipulation on them, and if you have

```
sym1 = :SYM
sym2 = :SYM
```

then it takes only a single comparison to test their equality. It demonstrates this clearly if we look at the object IDs for the strings and the symbols

```
puts str2.object_id
puts str1.object_id

puts sym1.object_id
puts sym2.object_id

puts str1.to_sym.object_id
puts str2.to_sym.object_id
```

**output**

```
22098264
22098228
203780
203780
203780
203780
```

So the two strings have different object IDs, whereas the two symbols are, in fact, the same object. Even converting the two strings to symbols gives the same object ID, so there is only *one* `:SYM`.

Because symbols are *values*, it makes no sense to write something like `:north = 1` as it is like writing `'north' = 1`.

Comparing strings to symbols, like `'north' = :north` will always return `false`, because they are different classes of object.

`param[:name]` works only because you can index a hash with *any object*. (You can say `param[Object.new] = 1`.) It's different from writing either `param['name']` (indexing the hash by a literal string) or `param[name]` (indexing the hash by the *contents* of variable `name`).

Does this answer your question?

Answer (score 4):

I see a misunderstanding of what symbols are and what is their purpose.

```
if direction == :north
```

In this line, `direction` is a **variable** (it can hold any value) and `:north` is a **value** (it can be assigned to variables).

Trying to do this:

```
:north = 1
```

is like trying to do

```
2 = 1
```

Which doesn't make sense, of course.